# hibernate and mysql and Operand should contain 2 column(s)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am getting a couple of exceptions:

1. First, `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper` - Operand should contain 2 column(s)
2. Second, `org.hibernate.exception.DataException`: could not extract ResultSet

My query is like *this*:

```
select *  from items 
where (appid, version) in (('abc', '123'), ('xyz', '456')
```

My JPA Repository is like *this*:

```
@Query(value = "select *  from items where (appid, version) in (:appIdVersionList)", nativeQuery = true)

List<Item> getItemList(@Param("appIdVersionList") String appIdVersionList);
```

If I were to do this, no exceptions:

```
@Query(value = "select *  from items where appid in (:appIdList) and version in (:versionList)", nativeQuery = true)
    
List<Item> getItems(@Param("appIdList") List<String> appIdList, @Param("versionList") List<String> versionList);
```

But the query that has no exception potentially could give me a result of `('abc', '456')`, which I don't want.

> What do I need to do to get rid of the exceptions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to columns but only one parameter. That will never work.

The only thing that will work is:

```
@Query(value = "select * from items where (appid, version) in (:appid, :version)", nativeQuery = true)
List getItemList(String appid, String version);
```

Otherwise you have to split it in two IN conditions.